# Giving error that the bind value at index 4 is null

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

```
String updateQuery ="INSERT INTO MAAccounts(userId, accountId, accountType, accountName, parentAccountId, currencyCode, isTransactionDefaultStatusOpen, currentBalance, monthlyBudget, createdOn, updatedOn) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
        String[] valVars = { 
                stringToDB(account.userId),
                integerToDB(account.accountId).toString(),
                integerToDB(account.accountType.getValue()).toString(),
                stringToDB(account.accountName),
                (integerToDB(account.parentAccountId) != null ? integerToDB(account.parentAccountId).toString() : null),
                stringToDB(account.currencyCode),
                boolToDB(account.isTransactionDefaultStatusOpen).toString(),
                CurrencyToDB(account.currentBalance).toString(),
                CurrencyToDB(account.monthlyBudget).toString(),
                dateToDB(now),
                "false"};

        Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(updateQuery, valVars);
```

Guys i am getting error , `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 4 is null`

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes when you are firing some query with `where clause` or `any other condition` with value as `null`.

Example- `select * from tbl_name where _id = null`

where as it should be

`select * from tbl_name where _id = some_id`

So debug and check that when your query is fired you have all your values that are used in building your query.

In your case it seems that this line,

```
(integerToDB(account.parentAccountId) != null ? 
                          integerToDB(account.parentAccountId).toString() : null)
```

is returning `null` so check this value.

Comment: there are atleast three values that are null. I have removed that integer line and placed a random string whose value is not null but problem still persists.

Comment: on which line you are getting error, you should post the logcat output in your question.

Comment: well it seems like i have passed random strings to all null values... and no problem occurred. Thanks for the answer. Can you tell how can i store the null in the database now whenever i pass null this error occurs?

Comment: You can store null value by passing it as String say `"null"` or `""`.

Comment: last point , can i do this  --Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(updateQuery, valVars);
     
      if (c != null)
      {
       mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
       mDb.endTransaction();
       return true;
   }
      else
      {
      mDb.endTransaction();
     return false;
     }

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the:  integerToDB(account.parentAccountId) returns null and then you set the value at index 4 to null:

```
(integerToDB(account.parentAccountId) != null ? integerToDB(account.parentAccountId).toString() : null)
```